# jquery each function only print the first item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to iterate over an array and only output the first item, and when iterating again, output the second item.

```
var array = [1,2,3]
iterate : function () {
  $.each(array, function(a,b) {
       console.log(a); // This will log 1 and 2 and 3
  });
```

This will log 1,2 and 3 but I just want to log 1 first and when the `iterate` function is called again, it will log 2 and then 3

I am assigning `iterate` function to a button (an increment button). So the increment button will simply output 1 when clicked first, and then 2 when clicked again, and then 3 when clicked again.

Comment: why not just create a counter function instead?

Comment: What you are looking for is an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Comment: What happens when you get to the last item of the array and you iterate again?

Comment: @RyanWilson no, it will stop iterating, so the increment button won't do anything, I will also have a decrement button, and that will decrease the array till 1, and after that it won't do anything.

Comment: @zuif I think you should build off of ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs idea about using a counter and just set a max and min

Comment: Any examples I can go through, I am very new to JS  @RyanWilson

Comment: @zuif I added an answer that shows how to implement this as a counter suggested by ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set two const variables to hold your minimum value and your maximum value, and declare a mutable variable for holding your count:

```
const min = 0;
const max = 4;
let counter = 0;

//function to reduce count if counter greater than min
function ReduceCount(){
  if(counter > min)
  {
     counter--;
  }
  console.log(counter);

}

//function to increase counter if less than max
function IncreaseCount(){
  if(counter < max)
  {
     counter++;
  }
  console.log(counter);

}

//Document Ready attach events for button clicks4
$(function(){
    //Attach click events
    $('#btnIncrease').on('click', function(){
           IncreaseCount();
     });

    $('#btnDecrease').on('click', function(){
           DecreaseCount();
     });
});

<button type="button" id="btnIncrease">Increase</button>
<button type="button" id="btnDecrease">Decrease</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would've done it

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
var index = 0;
function amClicked(){
  console.log(arr[index%arr.length]);
  index++
   if(index == arr.length){
     document.getElementById("yo").disabled = true;
}
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="yo" onclick="amClicked()" value="yo" />
```

Comment: I actually want to stop after 4, so `yo` button won't do anything after 4

Comment: so add a conditional, `if ( index > max) return; `

Comment: @Fallenreaper is right. Or you can disable the button as I did in my updated answer

Comment: thanks @Downvoters. I would appreciate an explanation